# How to Rebase with Multiple Stacked Branches in Git?

Tags: git

I'm wondering what the proper way to handle stacking of branches is in Git -- I've found that my flow breaks down after two stacks. Lets say I have the following setup:

```
c1 -> c2 -> c3 -> c4 //master
                   \
                    c5 - c6 //branch1
                           \
                            c7 - c8 // branch2
                                  \
                                   c9 - c10 // branch3
```

Lets say I decide to update branch1.

```
c1 -> c2 -> c3 -> c4 //master
                   \
                    c5 - c6 - c11//branch1
                           \
                            c7 - c8 // branch2
                                  \
                                   c9 - c10 // branch3
```

Then to update I would rebase branch2 onto branch1, and branch3 onto branch2 to ideally get the following:

```
c1 -> c2 -> c3 -> c4 //master
                   \
                    c5 - c6 - c11//branch1
                                \
                                 c7 - c8 // branch2
                                        \
                                         c9 - c10 // branch3
```

An issue I have, is that when there are merge conflicts between branch1 and branch2, and I fix them, those same merge conflicts then appear when I merge branch3 onto branch2. Actually, branch3 seems to contain the commits of branch2 for some reason, and when I rebase things get screwed up and I get a ton of merge conflicts as I'm merging later commits of branch2 into earlier commits of branch2 that for some reason live on branch3. Things thus look like this:

```
c1 -> c2 -> c3 -> c4 //master
                   \
                    c5 - c6 - c11//branch1
                                \
                                 c7 - c8  // branch2
                                         \
                                c7  - c8 - c9 - c10 // branch3
```

and the rebase turns into this:

```
c1 -> c2 -> c3 -> c4 //master
                   \
                    c5 - c6 - c11//branch1
                                \
                                 c7 - c8  // branch2
                                         \
                                         c7'  - c8' - c9 - c10 // branch3
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a different method of rebasing for stacked branches? Why does branch3 contain the commits of branch2?

Answer (score 6):

There is no good general-purpose tool to do what you want.  There are specific tricks that *may* work for you.  In particular, you will sometimes want `git rebase --onto` and you'll have to use it with care.

#### Background

The problem here is that Git branches do not nest, or stack, or whatever word you would like to use here.

More precisely, *branch names*, like `master` or `branch1` through `branch3`, simply act like pointers or labels.  Each one points to (or is pasted on to) *one particular* commit.  They don't have any inherent relationship to each other: you can add, remove, or move any label, anywhere, any time.  The only constraint on each label is that it must point to *exactly one* commit.

Commits are not so much *on **a** branch* as *contained **within** some **set** of branches*.  A given pair of commits may have a parent/child relationship.  In your drawings, for instance, commit `c1` is the parent of commit `c2`.  Git actually achieves this by having commits point to other commits, similar to the way branch names point to commits.  There is a difference though: the content of any one commit is frozen for all time, *including* its pointer.  What this means is that it's the *child* that points to the *parent*.  The parent exists when you make the child, but not vice versa, so the child can point to the parent, but not  vice versa.

(In effect, Git works backwards.  You've drawn your arrows going forwards, which is backwards for Git: the children point backwards, to the parents.)

Git needs a way to find each frozen-for-all-time commit.  The way is by their hash IDs: those big ugly strings of letters and digits (which is actually a 160-bit value expressed in hexadecimal).  In order to point to a commit, something—a branch name, or another commit—just contains the raw hash ID of the pointed-to commit.  If you have a hash ID—or if Git has one—you can have Git find the underlying object from that hash ID.<sup>1</sup>

Git defines the branch *name* to contain the raw hash ID of the *last* commit that is to be considered part of the chain of commits.  Previous commits, found by following the backwards-pointing arrows coming out of each commit, are *on* or *contained in* that branch.  So—here I'll switch to my usual notation of uppercase letters for each commit—if you have:

```
A <-B <-C <-D   <-- master
             \
              E <-F  <-- branch
```

then commit `F` is the *last* commit of `branch`, but `E`, `D`, and so on all the way back to `A` are all *contained in* `branch`.  Commit `D` is the *last* commit on `master`, but all of `A-B-C-D` are *in* `master`.

Note that when you first create a new branch name, it usually points to the same commit as some existing branch name:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E--F   <-- branch1, branch2
```

You have Git attach its `HEAD` to one of these branches, and make a new commit, which gets a new hash ID.  Git writes the *new* commit's hash ID into the branch name to which `HEAD` is attached:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E--F   <-- branch1
               \
                G   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

and all the invariants still hold: `branch2` contains the name (hash ID) of the *last* commit on that branch, `branch1` contains the hash ID of its last commit, `master` contains the name of its last commit, and so on.  No *commit* has *changed* (no part of any commit *can* change) but a *new* commit exists now, and the current branch still has `HEAD` attached to it, but has been dragged forward.

---

<sup>1</sup>Commits, in Git, are one of four kinds of internal *object* types.  The other three are *blob*, *tree*, and *tag* objects.  Normally the only Git hash IDs you interact with every day—e.g., with cut-and-paste to `git log` or `git show` or `git cherry-pick`, or in `git rebase -i` instruction sheets—are commit hash IDs.  Commits have a special property, which is that their contents are always unique, so that their hash IDs are also always unique.  Git guarantees this by adding a date-and-time stamp to each commit.  That, plus the fact that each commit holds the hash ID of its parent(s), is sufficient to produce the necessary uniqueness.

---

#### Rebase is about *copying* commits

As noted above, no part of any commit can ever be changed.  Commits are frozen for all time.  At most, you can simply stop *using* a commit.  Git *finds* commits by starting with the last ones—the branch tips—and working backwards, and if you do stop using a commit, and set things up so that Git can't *find* it, Git will eventually delete it for real.

You can, however, take a commit out—any commit, including a historical one—and work with it and then make a *new* commit from this.  It's probably worth a small side remark here about "detached HEAD" mode.

Let's say we have this—the same graph you drew, but using my single-letter style—with the same branch names:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E--F   <-- branch1
               \
                G--H   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
                    \
                     I--J   <-- branch3
```

The normal way of working with a commit is:

- We pick one by picking a branch name.
- Git attaches the special name `HEAD` to that branch name.
- That *branch name* is now the *current branch* and that *commit* is now the *current commit*.
- Git copies the frozen snapshot for that commit to Git's index and your work-tree (we won't go into the details here).

We can have Git extract commit `G`, though, by picking it out by its name: its unique hash ID.  When we do, we get a *detached HEAD* where `HEAD` itself points directly to the commit:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E--F   <-- branch1
               \
                G   <-- HEAD
                 \
                  H   <-- branch2
                   \
                    I--J   <-- branch3
```

If we were to make a new commit in this state, we would in fact get one.  I'll call it `X` rather than `K` since we'll just drop it and forget about it in a moment, but let's draw that result:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E--F   <-- branch1
               \
                G--X   <-- HEAD
                 \
                  H   <-- branch2
                   \
                    I--J   <-- branch3
```

Note how `X` is ordinary in all ways *except* that the only *name* that finds it is `HEAD`.  If we gave it a branch name, that would make the commit much more permanent: it would last until we deleted its branch name, or otherwise made the commit not-find-able.

Of course, that's not quite what you're doing.  Instead, you make a new commit, which I will call `K` (you called it `c11`) on `branch1` in the usual attached-HEAD way:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E--F--K   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
               \
                G--H   <-- branch2
                    \
                     I--J   <-- branch3
```

At this point, you'd like to copy commits `G-H-I-J` to new-and-improved commits.  The `git rebase` command can do this, as that is its job.  But let's look at *how* it does its job.

#### How rebase works

Since rebase is about *copying* (some) commits, its work is divided up into three phases:

1. Phase 1 is to decide *which commits to copy*.

   As you've seen, commits are often on *many* branches.  The ones we want to copy are those that are on *our* branch, but aren't also already somewhere else.  For instance, if we are on `branch2` now and we say `git rebase branch1`, we want to copy `G-H` but not `E-F` or any of the earlier commits.

   The main argument to `git rebase` is what the documentation calls the *`upstream`*.  Here, that's `branch1`.  The commits *to* copy are those reachable from our current branch—from `HEAD` or `branch2`; both select the same set of commits—*minus* those reachable from the name `branch1`.  So rebase first lists *all the commits on our current branch*, but then *knocks out* of the list of commits to copy, all those that are on the target/*`upstream`*.  This list ends up holding the raw hash IDs of the original commits.

   [The `git rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) describes this listing as:

   > All changes made by commits in the current branch but that are not in `<upstream>` are saved to a temporary area. This is the same set of commits that would be shown by `git log <upstream>..HEAD`; or by `git log 'fork_point'..HEAD`, if `--fork-point` is active (see the description on `--fork-point` below); or by `git log HEAD`, if the `--root` option is specified.

   This is, in fact, not the complete picture, but it's a good start.  We'll get to the more complete picture in the next section.
2. Phase 2 is about *actually copying the commits*.  Git uses `git cherry-pick`, or something mostly equivalent,<sup>2</sup> to do the copying.  We'll skip right over how cherry-pick works, except to mention that, as you have seen, it *can* get merge conflicts.

   What we will note here is that the copying takes place in *detached HEAD* mode.  Git first does a detached-HEAD style checkout of the target commit.  Here, since we said `git rebase branch1`, the target is commit `K`, so the copying starts with:

   ```
   A--B--C--D   <-- master
             \
              E--F--K   <-- branch1, HEAD
                  \
                   G--H   <-- branch2
                       \
                        I--J   <-- branch3
   ```

   with Git remembering the *name* `branch2` (in a file: if you poke around inside the `.git` directory during a partial rebase, you'll find a directory full of rebase state).

   The list of commits to copy at this point is commits `G` and `H`, in that order, and using their real hash IDs, whatever those really are.  Git copies these commits, one at a time, to new commits whose snapshots and parents are slightly different from the originals.  That gives us this new set of commits, still in detached-HEAD mode:

   ```
   A--B--C--D  ...    G'-H'  <-- HEAD
             \       /
              E--F--K   <-- branch1
                  \
                   G--H   <-- branch2
                       \
                        I--J   <-- branch3
   ```
3. The last phase of `git rebase` is to yank the branch name over.

   Git fishes out the saved branch name, forces it to point to the *current* (`HEAD`) commit—in this case `H'`—and re-attaches `HEAD`.  So now you have:

   ```
   A--B--C--D  ...    G'-H'  <-- branch2 (HEAD)
             \       /
              E--F--K   <-- branch1
                  \
                   G--H
                       \
                        I--J   <-- branch3
   ```

Note that there is, at this point, *no name* selecting commit `H` any more.<sup>3</sup>  We could straighten out the kink in the graph drawing, but I left it in for symmetry, and for another reason we'll see in a later section.

---

<sup>2</sup>Rebase can use one of several "back ends".  The default non-interactive back end has been `git-rebase--am` up until Git 2.26.0, but it isn't any more.  The `am` back-end uses `git format-patch` and `git am`, hence the name.  It misses certain file-rename cases, and is incapable of copying an empty-diff commit, but it can be a lot faster in some relatively rare rebase cases.

<sup>3</sup>Actually, there is at least one *reflog entry*, at least in a default setup.  We'll get to that later.

---

#### A better idea of what rebase copies

I mentioned above that in phase 1, when rebase lists out the commits to copy, it doesn't really use the `<upstream>..HEAD` method.  The documentation even has caveats here (about `fork-point` mode) but it does not have *enough* caveats.

Whenever you have Git copy commits—whether by running `git cherry-pick` yourself, or any other method including rebasing—you end up with commits that *may* "do the same thing" as each other.  That is, given commits `H` and `H'`, we could run:

```
git show <hash-of-H>
```

to view a diff between commit `G` and commit `H`, to see what `H` does.  We could run:

```
git show <hash-of-H'>
```

to view a diff between commit `G'` and commit `H'`, to see what `H'` does.

If we strip out the *line numbers* in this diff listing, we'll get the *same changes*.<sup>3</sup>  Git includes a command, `git patch-id`, that reads a diff listing, strips off the line numbers—and some white-space as well, so that, e.g., trailing white space doesn't affect things—and hashes the result.  This produces what Git calls a *patch ID*.

Unlike a commit's *hash* ID, which is guaranteed to be unique to that one particular commit—so that our cherry-picked copy is a *different* commit—the patch-ID is deliberately *the same* if the commit "does the same thing".  So:

```
git show <hash-of-either-H-or-H'> | git patch-id
```

will show that `H` and `H'` are "the same" commit, in a sense.

When you run `git rebase`, Git will actually compute the hash IDs of a bunch of commits.  For those that are "the same commit", Git will knock *those* commits out of the list of commits-to-copy.

(By default, rebase also knocks all *merge commits* out of the list.  You don't have any, in these examples, so we don't have to worry about these here.)

Hence if we now run:

```
git checkout branch3; git rebase branch2
```

Git will take this graph:

```
A--B--C--D  ...    G'-H'  <-- branch2
          \       /
           E--F--K   <-- branch1
               \
                G--H--I--J   <-- branch3 (HEAD)
```

and list commits `A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J` as the `branch3` list, but then knock out `A-B-C-D-E-F-K-G'-H'` because that's the `branch2` list.  That leaves `G-H-I-J` as the starting point *before* doing the patch-ID part.  In other words:

```
branch2..HEAD
```

is `G-H-I-J`.

But now, Git computes a patch ID for `G`, `H`, `I`, and `J`.  It then also computes patch IDs for `K`, `G'`, and `H'`.<sup>4</sup>  The rebase code finds that `G` already has a patch-ID equivalent commit, `G'`, in the upstream.  So `G'` gets knocked out of the list.  Then it finds that `H` has `H'` upstream too, so `H` gets knocked out of the list.

The final list of commits to copy at this point is `I-J`: just what you wanted.  Git can now detach `HEAD` at commit `H'` and copy `I-J`, and then re-attach `HEAD` to the result:

```
                        I'-J'  <-- branch3 (HEAD)
                       /
A--B--C--D  ...    G'-H'  <-- branch2
          \       /
           E--F--K   <-- branch1
               \
                G--H--I--J   [abandoned]
```

---

<sup>3</sup>More precisely, we'll *usually* get the same changes.  We sometimes won't get the same changes, if we had a merge conflict during the cherry-pick.

<sup>4</sup>The reason for this particular list is that these are the commits produced by `git rev-list branch2...HEAD`.  Note the three dots here: this is Git's syntax for a *symmetric difference* set operation.  This symmetric difference consists of commits reachable from `HEAD` but not `branch2`, plus commits reachable from `branch2` but not `HEAD`.  One set becomes the "left side" commits and one set becomes the "right side" commits.  The commits-to-copy are the left-side `G-H-I-J`, and all get patch-ID-ed; the commits in the upstream that *also* get patch-ID-ed are the right-side list.

---

#### Where this goes wrong

Footnote 3 (above) is the clue to where this goes wrong.  If, during conflict resolution, you wind up *changing* some commit in some substantive way, the patch-ID computations no longer work to knock out some commits.

When you go to rebase `branch3`, this time, Git chooses to copy `G` to `G'` again and/or copy `H` to `H'` again.  Each copy is nearly guaranteed to collide (as in merge-conflict) with the copy already present on the ongoing build of the new replacement commits.

The correct *action* is to *omit* `G` and `H` in the copying process.  Rebase would have done that for you, using the patch-ID trick, except that the patch-ID trick failed.

#### Using `--onto`

In your case, you want rebase to copy *some* commits but not *all* commits in the `<upstream>..HEAD` range while putting the copies at the right point.  You have:

```
A--B--C--D  ...    G'-H'  <-- branch2
          \       /
           E--F--K   <-- branch1
               \
                G--H--I--J   <-- branch3 (HEAD)
```

and you'd like to tell rebase: *Copy `I` and `J` but not `H` and therefore not `G`.  Put the copies after `H'` at the tip of `branch2`.*

*One* argument won't do the job, but *two* would.  Suppose you could say:

```
git rebase --dont <hash-of-H> --onto branch2    # not the actual syntax
```

for instance?  Fortunately, `git rebase` has this built in.  The actual syntax is:

```
git rebase --onto branch2 <hash-of-H>
```

The `--onto` argument lets you specify the *target* of the copies, freeing up the *`upstream`* argument to mean *what not to copy*.

Rebase will still do all the same patch-ID work, but by starting it with the list `G-H`, it doesn't have a chance to get it wrong.  The end result is just what you want.

#### Using the reflog, or other tricks, to find `H`

The annoying part here is finding `H`'s hash ID.  With these diagrams, I can blithely say `<hash-of-H>`, but in a real rebase, with real graphs and dozens of commits that all look alike, finding hash IDs is a pain in the butt.  If only there were an *easy* way to get this right.

As it turns out, there is.

Whenever Git *moves* a branch name, the way `git rebase` does for instance, it leaves a trail of *previous* values.  This trail goes into Git's *reflogs*.  There is a reflog for each branch name, plus one for `HEAD`.  The `HEAD` one is very active and not as useful here because it's *too* active, but the one for `branch2` is perfect.

Remember how we drew:

```
A--B--C--D  ...    G'-H'  <-- branch2 (HEAD)
          \       /
           E--F--K   <-- branch1
               \
                G--H
                    \
                     I--J   <-- branch3
```

originally.  I said I left it in for symmetry *and another reason*, and now it is time for the reason.  We can use the name `branch2@{1}` to refer to the *reflog entry* for "where `branch2` was one step / `branch2`-change ago".  As long as "one step ago" was just before rebasing, that means "commit `H`".  So:

```
git checkout branch3
git rebase --onto branch2 branch2@{1}
```

does the trick.

If you have done things in `branch2` since your rebase—e.g., if you built and tested and committed—you might need a higher number than `@{1}`.  Use `git reflog branch2` to print out the actual reflog contents, to check.

Another alternative is to drop a branch or tag name pointing to commit `H` *before* you rebase `branch2` at all.  For instance, if you make a new name `branch2-old` or `branch2.0` or whatever, you'll still have:

```
A--B--C--D  ...    G'-H'  <-- branch2
          \       /
           E--F--K   <-- branch1
               \
                G--H   <-- branch2-old
                    \
                     I--J   <-- branch3
```

(regardless of where `HEAD` is now).  You can mark commit `J` as `branch3-old` before you start *its* rebase, too.

(The reflogs are convenient and normally work fine.  Branch names are cheap, though.)

#### Consider also doing the one-fell-swoop rebase

Suppose you have this graph:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E--F--U   <-- branch1
               \
                G--H   <-- branch2
                    \
                    ...
                      \
                       T   <-- branch9
```

where `U` is the new commit you'd like to have in all `branchN` ancestries.  If you run:

```
git checkout branch9; git rebase branch1
```

you'll get copies of commits `G-H-...--T`, all in one operation.  You can now take `branch2`, `branch3`, ..., up through `branch8` and just move each one to point to the appropriate copied commit.  Matching up the original commits with their copies is a job for a tool, but unfortunately, that tool does not exist.  So if you go this way, it's kind of manual.

Also, be aware that this *doesn't* work for some cases:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E--F--K   <-- branch1
               \
                G--H--L   <-- branch2
                    \
                     I--J   <-- branch3
```

Rebasing `branch3` onto `branch1` copies only `G-H-I-J`, not `L`.  So you may still need the occasional `git rebase --onto` as well.  (A proper tool would do all of this.)

Comment: There is now an open-source CLI tool for performing recursive rebases of branches: https://github.com/screenplaydev/graphite-cli

Comment: Ancestor branches do stack now with `git rebase --update-refs`.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR use / copy the implementation of [Graphite CLI](https://github.com/screenplaydev/graphite-cli)

The previous answer is outdated.

> "There is no good general-purpose tool to do what you want."

This open-source CLI will perform recursive branch rebases (disclosure, I'm a contributor):
https://github.com/screenplaydev/graphite-cli

The main rebase-recursion can be seen here: https://github.com/screenplaydev/graphite-cli/blob/dfe4390baf9ce6aeedad0631e41c9f1bdc57ef9a/src/actions/fix.ts#L60

```
git rebase --onto ${parentBranch.name} ${mergeBase} ${currentBranch.name}
```

The key insight is to store branch parents in git refs, in order to recurse the DAG during operations. Without parent metadata, it would be impossible to always determine the merge-base of successive child branches.

```
const metaSha = execSync(`git hash-object -w --stdin`, {input: JSON.stringify(desc)}).toString();

execSync(`git update-ref refs/branch-metadata/${this.name} ${metaSha}`);
```

https://github.com/screenplaydev/graphite-cli/blob/dfe4390baf9ce6aeedad0631e41c9f1bdc57ef9a/src/wrapper-classes/branch.ts#L102-L109